# To split records in one column into multiple columns

Tags: sql-server

I am not sure whether this is achievable in sql server or not. I have a table ADDRESS and its metadata is given below. SQ_ID is my unique key column

```
SQ_ID INT
ADDRESS_LINE_1 varchar(255)
ADDRESS_LINE_2 varchar(255)
ADDRESS_LINE_3 varchar(255)
ADDRESS_LINE_4 varchar(255)
REGION varchar(255)
POSTOCODE varchar(255)
COUNTRY_CODE varchar(255)
```

Now I have loaded around 2 millions of records into this table and the problem is that all the address details have been loaded into ADDRESS LINE 1 column in this table. Now I am trying to find a way to split this. Below given is some of the sample set of addresses.

[image]

So I want to split the data in Address line 1 in such a way that

> value in  addressLine1 in the given record should be populated to
>   addressline1 in the same table value in  addressLine2 in the given
>   record should be populated to addressline2 in the same table value in 
>   addressLine3 in the given record should be populated to addressline3
>   in the same table value in  primaryTown in the given record should be
>   populated to addressline4 in the same table value in provinceOrState
>   in the given record should be populated to region in the same table
>   value in isoAlpha2Code in the given record should be populated to
>   COUNTRY_CODE in the same table value in zipOrPostalCode in the given
>   record should be populated to POSTOCODE in the same table

My Expected output is given below

[image]

Also I am attaching set of sample address values for testing

```
{'addressLine1': '67 xxxx Road', 'primaryTown': 'HOxxxCHxxCH',
 'zipOrPostalCode': 'RM11 1EX', 'addressCountry': {'isoAlpha2Code':
 'GB'}}

{'primaryTown': 'MünXXer', 'addressCountry': {'isoAlpha2Code': 'DE'}}

{'addressLine1': '28 THE EXCAC', 'primaryTown': 'PERTH',
'provinceOrState': 'WA', 'addressCountry': {'isoAlpha2Code': 'AU'}}

{'addressLine1': '28 THE ESPLANADE', 'primaryTown': 'PERTH',
'provinceOrState': 'WA', 'addressCountry': {'isoAlpha2Code': 'AU'}}

{'addressLine1': '76 XXX STREET', 'primaryTown': 'MAXDFOT',
'provinceOrState': 'NSW', 'addressCountry': {'isoAlpha2Code': 'AU'}}

{'addressLine1': 'UNIT 56', 'addressLine2': '22 XDFR STREET',
'primaryTown': 'MANLY VALE', 'provinceOrState': 'NSW',
'addressCountry': {'isoAlpha2Code': 'AU'}}

{'addressLine1': 'BjoXCDSaret 15', 'addressLine2': 'Jppsdeheim',
'addressLine3': '', 'primaryTown': 'AKERdwfUS', 'addressCountry':
{'isoAlpha2Code': 'NO'}}
```

Comment: What do you mean `split`? And why do you want *that*? Those aren't lines concatenated together, they are complex JSON objects. You can't parse them with splitting

Comment: SQL Server 2016 and later supports JSON data. You can use eg `JSON_VALUE(address_Line_1,'$.addressCountry.isoAlpha2Code')` to get `GB`. From a design perspective, there's no reason to extract those values in separate fields unless you need them for querying and indexing. Extracting the PostCode or CountryCode can be useful. Address lines on the other hand are just information that can't be used in a query

Comment: Which version of MS Sql Server?  If it's at least 2016, then it's easy to do with the [JSON functions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/json-functions-transact-sql)

Comment: Actually I need to separate that into different columns to query and also to do my development where I am doing data quality check and standardization

Comment: @GIN you are doing the exact opposite in that case. You still haven't said which SQL Server version you target. 2016 and later can use `JSON_VALUE` or `OPENJSON`. Earlier versions require other tricks

Comment: @GIN, I think what LukStorms is trying to say is, JSON Functions will definitely solve you problem. After a few click on LukStorms's link, I managed to understand what JSON Functions do, see this [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/json/json-data-sql-server?view=sql-server-2017)

Comment: I am using SQL Server 2014 version.

Answer (score 2):

You can't parse JSON by splitting. SQL Server 2016 and later supports JSON though, so you can extract the data you want using functions like [JSON_VALUE](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/json-value-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017).

You don't *have* to do that though, unless you want to index and filter those values. It may make sense to extract the country or zip code if you intend to filter or group results using them. Address lines on the other hand can't be queried and might as well remain in the JSON string. You can always extract them when necessary with JSON_VALUE.

Puttin `primaryTown` in `AddressLine4` looks like a mistake though. That *is* a significant attribute that could be used in querying. It should go to its own field, or not extracted at all.

**SQL Server 2016 and later**

In any case, you can parse a JSON value with `JSON_VALUE` , eg :

```
declare @myTable table(json varchar(max))

insert into @myTable
values
('{"addressLine1": "BjoXCDSaret 15", "addressLine2": "Jppsdeheim","addressLine3": "", "primaryTown": "AKERdwfUS", "addressCountry":
{"isoAlpha2Code": "NO"}}'),
('{"addressLine1": "67 xxxx Road", "primaryTown": "HOxxxCHxxCH",
 "zipOrPostalCode": "RM11 1EX", "addressCountry": {"isoAlpha2Code":
 "GB"}}'),
('{"primaryTown": "MünXXer", "addressCountry": {"isoAlpha2Code": "DE"}}'),
('{"addressLine1": "28 THE EXCAC", "primaryTown": "PERTH",
"provinceOrState": "WA", "addressCountry": {"isoAlpha2Code": "AU"}}'),
('{"addressLine1": "28 THE ESPLANADE", "primaryTown": "PERTH",
"provinceOrState": "WA", "addressCountry": {"isoAlpha2Code": "AU"}}'),
('{"addressLine1": "76 XXX STREET", "primaryTown": "MAXDFOT",
"provinceOrState": "NSW", "addressCountry": {"isoAlpha2Code": "AU"}}'),
('{"addressLine1": "UNIT 56", "addressLine2": "22 XDFR STREET",
"primaryTown": "MANLY VALE", "provinceOrState": "NSW",
"addressCountry": {"isoAlpha2Code": "AU"}}')

select 
    JSON_VALUE(json,'$.zipOrPostalCode') as ZipCode,
    JSON_VALUE(json,'$.primaryTown') as primaryTown,
    JSON_VALUE(json,'$.addressCountry.isoAlpha2Code') as CountryCode
from @mytable
```

You can use the same expressions to create persisted computed columns on the table and index them, thus speeding queries that need to filter by country or zip code.

**Older versions**

In older versions, perhaps the simplest solution would be to create a SQLCLR function that uses JSON.NET to parse the data and return the values.

Another option is to convert the JSON string to XML using string replacements and use XPATH to retrieve values. This can get really tricky though as the replacements depend on the expected data, are sensitive to whitespace and can easily break when dealing with nested objects.

For example, this flat JSON object :

```
declare @json varchar(max)='{"addressLine1": "BjoXCDSaret 15", "addressLine2": "Jppsdeheim", "addressLine3": "", "primaryTown": "AKERdwfUS"}'
```

Can be converted to XML with a few replacements. Notice that I fixed whitespace differences to ensure there's always a space between tokens. Otherwise I'd have to replace both `","` and `", "`.

```
select 
    cast(
        replace(
            replace(
                replace(
                    replace(@json,'{"','<it '),
                '": "',' ="'),
            '", "','" '),
        '}',' />')
    as xml)
```

The result is :

```
<it addressLine1="BjoXCDSaret 15" addressLine2="Jppsdeheim" addressLine3="" primaryTown="AKERdwfUS" />
```

This can now be queried with [.value](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/xml/value-method-xml-data-type?view=sql-server-2017) :

```
select 
    cast(replace(replace(replace(replace(@json,'{"','<it '),'": "',' ="'),'", "','" '),'}',' />') as xml)       
     .value('(/it/@primaryTown)[1]','varchar(20)')
```

This will return :

```
AKERdwfUS
```

This breaks with the nested `addressCountry` object though. If you *know* what the JSON text contains, you could cheat and replace specific attributes, not just separators, eg :

```
declare @json varchar(max)='{"addressLine1": "UNIT 56", "addressLine2": "22 XDFR STREET", "primaryTown": "MANLY VALE", "provinceOrState": "NSW", "addressCountry": {"isoAlpha2Code": "AU"}}'
select      
cast(
    replace(
        replace(
            replace(
                replace(
                    replace(
                        replace(@json,'", "addressCountry": {"','"><addressCountry '),
                        '}}','/></it>'),
                    '{"','<it '),
                '": "',' ="'),
            '", "','" ')
        ,'}',' />') 
    as xml).value('(/it/addressCountry/@isoAlpha2Code)[1]','varchar(20)')
```

This returns `AU`.

That's some serious cheating though that can only work through trial and error. In this case, the `addressCountry` attribute and the following separators are converted to an element. `}}` is expected to appear only at the end of the string, so it gets special treatment.

**Use a client script**

It's probably easier to use a small .NET program to read the data using JSON.NET and extract the desired values. 2M rows aren't a lot so parsing the data once in a while won't be a big problem

Comment: Since I am using sql server 2014 , I dont think so , I would be able to use the above query

Comment: @GIN you should have specified that at the start. I added a couple of options for older versions. They aren't trivial. 2M rows isn't a lot though. Why not move it to a more recent database version?

Comment: Thanks Panagiotis. I am planning to implement this change using another application which will be easier